# Android Google Maps V2 Load into Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps, android-maps-v2

I have list_detail layout using fragments, showing list of saved places on the map, when the application first started, the first place is selected, the map gets initialized and camera position changes successfully to that location, but when selecting another place or even selecting the same location again the map is drawn but camera position is not changed.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bundle) {
    mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_layout, container,false);
    mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.map_fragment_container, mapFragment).commit();
    updateUI();
    return mainLayout ;
}
```

and in my `updateUI()` method i change the camera position.

I had the same issue with another application, I solved that issue by using `SupportMapFragment` in the layout file not as above programmatically.

Any ideas? is there any issues using map fragment like I did?

Please note that even in the samples supplied by Google, there is not even a single sample on how to work with the new API inside a fragment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok this was my fault, my map object was defined as STATIC in my code, removed the static declaration and everything is working fine now.

Comment: glad you have found out your issue.

Comment: Can you please help me to place a Google mapv2 in custom layout?

Comment: @Akhil what exactly you want to do ? you can post your question here or in a new post and i will try to help you